# How to make the area above UITableView transparent

Tags: ios, uitableview, transparent

My original necessary was to make the area above uitableview transparent and show the imageview under it, just like this:

[image]

I know there are many ways to implement this effect and I just wonder why cells can be transparent and show the content under them but the area above uitableview can't. Is there any way?

Comment: Put a header view with clear color.

Comment: plz show me your code of  UITableView delegate and data source methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want transparent area only once then create `UIView` with background color `clearColor`. And set `UITableView` header view `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;`

If you want transparent area for every section then -

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     //return height of transparent area
}
```

then,

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      // return UIView with clearColor.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the `UITableView` to clearColor

Comment: Already make background color of UITableView clearColor, otherwise  can't see the image in the first cell

Comment: Please explain the whole setup - does the area above the tableview belong to it? Is it the table header perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

make ui tableview background color as clear color

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a grouped Table View(I cant see the image you provided):

```
[self.tblView setBackgroundView:nil];
```